# Convert comma seperated string from ARG into array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to take an arg like "this, is, a, test" and create an array in powershell?

Something like

```
./myScript.ps1 -myStringArray 'this, is, a, test'
```

And in the code something like:

```
param (
    [string[]] $myStringArray = @()
)

foreach($item in $myStringArray) {
    Write-Host $item
}
```

I have tried a few way but they aren't very clean and either create a sentence with or without the commas but no new line per item.

How difficult would it be to support both:
`'this, is, a, test'`
And
`'this,is,a,test'`?

Comment: What about `("this, is, a, test" -split ',').trim()`

Comment: Note that PowerShell already allows you to pass array literals as argument: `./myScript.ps1 -myStringArray this, is, a, 'better test'`, in which case you don't need to split anything on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-split` operator with a simple *regex* to archive that:

```
param (
    [string[]] $myStringArray = @()
)

$myStringArray -split ',\s?' | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_
}
```

Comment: Nice! For more flexible whitespace handling you might want to use `'\s*,\s*'` to remove any number of whitespace chars before and after the comma.